# Accessing Sharepoint File and FileType Using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am currently adapting existing c# and trying to identify filetype from when a file is uploaded. The following

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        commentscheck(properties);
    }
```

The commentscheck function that is called from this function is attempting to verify what filetype something is.

I was wondering whether I could access something from SPItemEventProperties that would be able to tell me the filetype that has been uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the properties.AfterUrl and split it.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    string[] FileTypeParts = properties.AfterUrl.Split(".");
    string fileType = FileTypeParts [FileTypeParts .length-1];
    string FileNameParts = properties.AfterUrl.Split("/");
    string FileName = FileNameParts [FileNameParts .length-1];
    commentscheck(properties);
}
```